# Получить часть url (id)

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть код

```
<?php
$js=file_get_contents('https://glopart.ru/ads/adunit/5697/script.js');
  if(preg_match('#push\((?<json>.*?)\);#',$js,$match)){
    $wares=json_decode($match['json'])->wares;
    foreach ($wares as $item) {
    echo '<a href="'.$item->url.'" class="blue3" target="_blank">ссылка</a>';
  }
}
?>
```

Результат выполнения ссылки следующего вида glopart.ru/ads/adunit/5697/click/**106807**

Пожалуйста, помогите под строкой

`echo '<a href="'.$item->url.'" class="blue3" target="_blank">ссылка</a>';`

вывести конечный id ссылки, в примере это **106807**

Главное условие последний слеш, далее это то, что нужно вытащить.

Т.е. нужно как-то на лету получить не только ссылку но и последний каталог, так пробовал

```
<?php
$js=file_get_contents('https://glopart.ru/ads/adunit/5697/script.js');
  if(preg_match('#push\((?<json>.*?)\);#',$js,$match)){
    $wares=json_decode($match['json'])->wares;
    foreach ($wares as $item) {
    echo '<a href="'.$item->url.'" class="blue3" target="_blank">ссылка</a>';

    preg_match('/\w+$/', $item->url, $match);
    echo '<a href="'.$match.'" class="blue3" target="_blank">каталог</a>';
  }
}
?>
```

вместо id выводит Array   :(

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [функцией `basename()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.basename.php):

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>   Возвращает последний компонент имени из указанного пути.

```
echo '<a href="' . basename( $item->url ) . '" class="blue3" target="_blank">каталог</a>';
```

А ваш код выводит `Array`, потому что [там, действительно, массив](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php):

> В случае, если указан дополнительный параметр `matches`, он будет заполнен результатами поиска. Элемент `$matches[0]` будет содержать часть строки, соответствующую вхождению всего шаблона, `$matches[1]` — часть строки, соответствующую первой подмаске, и так далее.

Comment: Спасибо! Я делал $matches[1] но получал ошибку.